# Set maxdate in sharepoint datepicker control

Tags: sharepoint-server, datepicker

We have OOTB New item form with date time field. We need to restrict users to select future date for Time field. So We want to disable (gray out) the future dates.

How we can achieve this? Any help will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by adding some javascript/jquery in the page. Today's date in calendar has the **td** class **ms-picker-today**. Take this class and then select all td after this class with class **ms-picker-daycenter** and apply css as disabled.

Try out, it should work.

Comment: thanks ankit for reply..i tried this one but its not working.. this is my code `$(document).ready(function(){
$("td.ms-picker-today").nextAll("td.ms-picker-daycenter").prop('disabled', true);
alert("disabled");
});`  on page load todays date having same class 'ms-picker-daycenter' and i assume thats why its not working. but i also tried by replacing 'ms-picker-today' with 'ms-picker-daycenter' but still no luck. any idea?

Comment: u get the alert?

Comment: and is it working in developer tool?

Comment: Not getting alert. but when i use ".css("display","none")" instead of ".prop('disabled', true)", then i getting alert but td is not becoming display none.  but display none is working on developer tool.

Comment: ok..try adding .attr("disabled","disabled")

Comment: display none is working on developer tool and not from the script because the dom is not loaded. Add your function inside window.load instead of document.ready()

Comment: after adding .attr("disabled","disabled") i am getting alert but elements are not getting disabled. also tried with both window.load & document.ready()

Comment: try .prop("disabled","disabled")

Comment: hope you have used the window.load syntax correctly it will be like this:

$(window).load(function{});

Comment: yes i am using it correctly. but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the “`Validation setting`” for SharePoint list.
Consider Start Date is your column which needs to validate.

Set the formula as `“=[Start Date]<=Today()”`

This will let user select future date, but will not allow him to submit the form. You can put your own custom message.

Comment: Thank you. But we already tried that one and client don't want like this.

Comment: do you want it on OOTB form itself?

Comment: Yes..On OOTB Form.

Comment: OOTB form you will need to do some customization using designer

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can use jQuery bind to attach another event to the calendar control. to pre check if the selected date is greater that today.

I could see the code here, where you are supposed to apply the bind call.

```
<td class="ms-picker-daycenter" onmouseover="this.className='ms-picker-daycenterOn';" onmouseout="this.className='ms-picker-daycenter';" onclick="javascript:ClickDay('6\u002f10\u002f2018')"><a id="20180610" href="javascript:ClickDay('6\u002f10\u002f2018')"><span class="ms-accessible">June</span>10<span class="ms-accessible"> 2018</span></a></td>
```